# Combining features with same value using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I’m looking to combine several features with same value (in same layer) so the remaining attributes of that combined feature are united together in the same cell and organized comma separated or similar. I know Global Mapper has this tool.

Is it posible to achieve this in ArcGIS Desktop?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is de-normalize the database for one attribute. That is not supported by many pieces of software, for a lot of reasons. For one, it is not so easy to search or update compound delimited fields. ArcGIS does support having one shape record and multiple related attribute values for the same field using Relate and relationship tools.

That said, the Dissolve geoprocessing tool, selecting your field to dissolve on, will get you one record. You would have to Summarize on that field in your (original) table to preserve all of the attribute values because Dissolve will only keep one. You will then have a related table based on the matching attributed values. I think a simple Python program could write the Summarize table results to your field using delimiters of your choice.